# Building Boost 1.59 with Intel C++ Compiler 15.0 in Centos 7

Tags: c++, linux, boost, centos7, icc

I am trying to build Boost 1.59 with Intel C++ Compiler 15.0 in Centos 7. I am using the below command.

```
./bootstrap.sh --without-libraries=mpi,python
./b2 toolset=intel-15.0 address-model=64 cxxflags="-std=c++11" --layout=versioned link=static variant=debug,release
```

I got the below error in building Boost.Log. Could you please help? I tried to compile with GCC 4.8 and it works. Is it a bug in Intel C++ Compiler?

```
intel-linux.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/log/build/intel-linux-15.0/debug/link-static/log-api-unix/threading-multi/default_filter_factory.o
./boost/fusion/algorithm/query/detail/find_if.hpp(208): internal error: assertion failed at: "shared/cfe/edgcpfe/lower_il.c", line 18968

              return recursive_call(iter, found());
              ^

compilation aborted for libs/log/src/default_filter_factory.cpp (code 4)

"icpc" -c -xc++ -O0 -g -w1 -inline-level=0 -pthread -m64 -fvisibility=hidden -std=c++11 -wd177,780,2196,1782,193,304,981,1418,411,734,279 -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DBOOST_CHRONO_STATIC_LINK=1 -DBOOST_FILESYSTEM_STATIC_LINK=1 -DBOOST_LOG_SETUP_BUILDING_THE_LIB=1 -DBOOST_LOG_USE_AVX2 -DBOOST_LOG_USE_NATIVE_SYSLOG -DBOOST_LOG_USE_SSSE3 -DBOOST_LOG_WITHOUT_EVENT_LOG -DBOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3=1 -DBOOST_SYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED -DBOOST_SYSTEM_STATIC_LINK=1 -DBOOST_THREAD_BUILD_LIB=1 -DBOOST_THREAD_DONT_USE_CHRONO=1 -DBOOST_THREAD_POSIX -DBOOST_THREAD_USE_LIB=1 -DDATE_TIME_INLINE -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600 -I"."   -c -o "bin.v2/libs/log/build/intel-linux-15.0/debug/link-static/log-api-unix/threading-multi/default_filter_factory.o" "libs/log/src/default_filter_factory.cpp"

...failed intel-linux.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/log/build/intel-linux-15.0/debug/link-static/log-api-unix/threading-multi/default_filter_factory.o...
intel-linux.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/log/build/intel-linux-15.0/debug/link-static/log-api-unix/threading-multi/matches_relation_factory.o
./boost/fusion/algorithm/query/detail/find_if.hpp(208): internal error: assertion failed at: "shared/cfe/edgcpfe/lower_il.c", line 18968

              return recursive_call(iter, found());
              ^

compilation aborted for libs/log/src/matches_relation_factory.cpp (code 4)
```

Comment: Yes, the "internal error" indicates it's a problem with the Intel compiler. The support folks would like to know about it, so you could report it here: https://software.intel.com/en-us/c-compilers/ipsxe-support

Comment: Thx Micah, I just posted again in the intel forum.